# Unsmooth Transition Animation if Target is Below Overlapping Element

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I'm animating a fade activity transition with an image as shared element. The destination container is supposed to be partially hidden underneath another element having `app:behavior_overlapTop`, in this case a NestedScrollView. However in reality this element materializes below the image and abruptly overlaps it at the end of animation. This creates an unsmooth feel like this:

[image: Problem Ilustration]

This is the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.mypackage.android.view.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:transitionName="@string/trans_gallery_img"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="45dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    ... stuff
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The transition I use:

```
Fade fade = new Fade();
fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);
getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
getWindow().setExitTransition(fade);

ChangeBounds changeBoundsTransition = new ChangeBounds();
getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(changeBoundsTransition);
getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(changeBoundsTransition);
```

Even if I use Slide, it will have the same effect with the overlapping element sliding below before ending in the same way. It would be nice to have a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

To properly display the animation, the `shared element` is drawn overlaying the `no-shared elements` and will come back to the normal window's View hierarchy when the animation ends.
This means that during the animation the `shared element` will be above the `NestedScrollView` and abruptly will return to his normal state below the `NestedScrollView` when the transitions end (`EnterTransition` and `SharedElementEnterTransition`).

I know two options to manage this:

1.-Add `android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay="false"`to your style.xml:

The animation don't overlay the rest of the views and you will only see the animation inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

[image]

2.- Wait to the shared element transition end before start your `fade in` animation for the `NestedScrollView`:

Set `NestedScrollView` visibility to `invisible`

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    ...
    android:visibility="invisible"
    >
```

set a Listener to wait for the shared element transition ends and start a animation for the `NestedScrollView`

```
getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition().addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {

        ...

        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
            Animator anim   = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myNestedScrollView, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
            anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            anim.setDuration(1000);
            ns.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            anim.start();


        }

        ...

    });
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually upon closer look, the animating element overlays everything including the Up button on top left screen. This happens on both my and your second gif. It would be great if your fade-in solution can be used on Up button too.